# Swift: multipart formdata with image got issues

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, afnetworking

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager(baseURL: NSURL(string: strURL))
    print("pram is  \(manager)")

    manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()

    //   let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(param!, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")!, 0.5)

    let op : AFHTTPRequestOperation = manager.POST("data", parameters: param, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData: AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
        formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData!, name: "photo", fileName: "photo.png", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

        //  print(op)
        },
        success:
        {
            (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            print(responseObject)
        },
        failure: { (operation, error) in
         print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    })!

    op.start()
}
```

I try this code to multiform but return 400

I want to send like

```
{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","dob":"1990-01-02","gender":"M","ph

one_no":"9988475","email":"j.d@gmail.com","password":"john.doe","user_type":"U","facebook_id":""}
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename=""
Content-Type: 


----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

I want to send my data to server something like what I posted.I tried this code to acheive but I can't.Please help me solve this issues